# Проблема со стилем Android

Tags: java, android

Товарищи, как лечить? Заменил стиль в манифесте выдает такую сводочку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проще всего не обращать внимания и не использовать превью. Это лишь первая щамеченная вами в нём проблема

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте почистить кэш. `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart`